# Error turf is not defined in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, import, turf

Here is my `package.json` :

```
"name": "api_geoservices",
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"start": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"serve": "vite preview",
"test": "node test.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
"vite": "^4.0.4"
},
"dependencies": {
"@turf/centroid": "^6.5.0",
"ol": "latest",
"ol-ext": "^4.0.13",
"proj4": "^2.9.2"
 }
}
```

You can see that the centroid module is installed.

In main.js, I am using the `centroid` module like this:

```
*imports*
import centroid from "@turf/centroid"
...
const featuresPoint = []
turf.featureEach(reponse, function (operation) {
  const centroide = turf.centroid(operation)
  const pointCentroid = opeGeoJsonFormat.readFeature(centroide)
  featuresPoint.push(pointCentroid)
....
})
```

In the browser, the console logs out `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: turf is not defined`. It seems that `turf` is not a global variable (?).   I can't see what I missed in the [doc](https://turfjs.org/getting-started).

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js, but looking at https://turfjs.org/getting-started/ it seems that when you import single function/method, you have to use it without `turf.` qualifier, like `centroid`.

Comment: Then I can't use turf's method `featureEach`. One solution is to call the script (cdn) in html file. I would have preferred to stick with `import' but nothing's perfect.

Comment: This is not GIS related problem and as such more suitable for StackOverflow site. It seems so basic that it must have some reasonable solution.